# Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION in ASP.NET MVC 4 C# Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys, code-first

How do I specify ON DELETE NO ACTION Foreign Key Constraint in my model designs?

At present, I have:

```
public class Status
{
    [Required]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Restuarant
{
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public List<Menu> Menus { get; set; }

    // NAVIGATION PROPERTIES
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class Menu
{
    public int MenuId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    // NAVIGATION PROPERTIES
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
}
```

And my DbContext:

```
public class MenuEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see:

- a Restaurant has many menus
- a Restaurant has one status
- a Menu belongs to 1 restaurant
- **Both Restaurants and Menus have 1 status. (Live, Invisible, Draft)**

Naturally, if a status is deleted, I certainly don't want to cascade as this will muck everything up.

**UPDATE:**

Mark Oreta mentions using the following in his example below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FirstEntity>() 
    .HasMany(f => f.SecondEntities) 
    .WithOptional() 
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Where do I put this code? Within my MenuEntities / DbContext class? 
Can anybody provide an example of this being used?

**UPDATE:** 
Got this bit working now, however this has created a multiplicity constraint error when trying to seed the DB...

```
Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Menu_Status_Source' of the relationship 'LaCascadaWebApi.Models.Menu_Status' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.
```

My Database Initialiser:

http://pastebin.com/T2XWsAqk

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can either disable it for your entire context by removing the cascade delete convention in the OnModelCreating method:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
  {
     modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
  }
```

or, you can do it per relationship using a fluent mapping (also in the OnModelCreating):

**EDIT: you would put it in your menu entities**

```
public class MenuEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Menu> Menus { get; set; }

      protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
      {

         modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

     modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>()
        .HasRequired( f => f.Status )
        .WithRequiredDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );

     modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
        .HasRequired( f => f.Status )
        .WithRequiredDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );

      }

}
```

Comment: Where is the OnModelCreating method? How can I find it?

Comment: Updated my answer - but you would put it in your MenuEntities class, you wouldn't need to put both the removal of the convention and the fluent mapping (pick one or the other), but I put both so you could see how you would use them.

Comment: Thanks Mark, Updated, but still problems... See Update in question

Comment: Updated my fluent - I set it up wrong the first time, my apologies!

Comment: thanks, updated, but still same error. I think it may be because of how i set up the restaurant model and how i am trying to seed the menus??? separate issue?

Comment: Its possible - with the code above I was able to create a quick test app which was able to make a menu/status/restaurant/status

Comment: it's possible to just set on model, not in identity model or just no delete for one model

Answer (score 42):

Just make the FK property nullable, then the cascade delete will be gone.

```cs
public int? StatusId { get; set; }
```

Comment: fastest and simplest method

Comment: Your answer is a worth of 1000 up-votes. But; sorry, I gave just one due to stackoverflow website validation logic.

Comment: After making the changes to the model, make sure you regenerate the migration file

Answer (score 1):

After making the changes to the model, make sure you regenerate the migration file by adding the -Force parameter.

Add-Migration MigrationName -Force

Answer (score 1):

add this line to end of the field in the context;

.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your `MenuEntities` class (class that descend from `DbContext`):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In new Entity Framework those solutions doesn't work. You need to do it differently, here is the code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    if (modelBuilder == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");

    // for the other conventions, we do a metadata model loop
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        // equivalent of modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        entityType.SetTableName(entityType.DisplayName());

        // equivalent of modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        entityType.GetForeignKeys()
            .Where(fk => !fk.IsOwnership && fk.DeleteBehavior == DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(fk => fk.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Solution by Dennes Torres, source: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/change-delete-behavior-and-more-on-ef-core/

You need to place this code in the class delivering from DbContext.